# Handling duplicates in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pulling cryptocurrency data from binance API and storing it in an database, its working, but how do I work around duplicates in the database? If I run the for loop a second time, it raises

> ValueError: Table "'BTCUSDT' already exists."

How do stop it from creating a new table and just inserting a value if it's not already there using a timestamp as the key?

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///Cryptoprices3.db')

def getminutedata(symbol, lookback):
    frame = pd.DataFrame(client.get_historical_klines(symbol,'1m',lookback + ' days ago UTC' ))

    frame = frame.iloc[:,:6]
    frame.columns = ['Time','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume']
    frame[['Open','High','Low','Close','Volume']] = frame[['Open','High','Low','Close','Volume']].astype(float)
    frame.Time = pd.to_datetime(frame.Time, unit='ms')
    return frame


for coin in coins:
    getminutedata(coin,'2').to_sql(coin, engine, index=False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the pandas "drop_duplicates" method?

`frame.drop_duplicates()` should take care of this.

Comment: So this will remove all duplicates in the dataframe very nice!, what if i allready have duplicates in the DB? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `if_exists="append"` to `to_sql`, which will add your new table as rows below the existing table.

Source: [pandas docs for `to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)